GNC C: Ideas over main starting point confusions?
An extremely simple problem demonstration:
#include <stdio.h>


void myFunc()
{
    puts("Greetings, Code 'Mon ...");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("zMain 01.\n");
    myFunc();
    puts("zMain 02.\n");
}

Target main_test2.run emits "file not found" as made via gcc on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS:
...
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401030
...
/main_test/yikes01$ ./main_test2.run
bash: ./main_test2.run: No such file or directory

The same runs, yet ignores main() as the |starting| point on MinGW / Windows 10:
c:\tmp\main_test\yikes01>main_test2.run
Greetings, Code 'Mon ...

c:\tmp\main_test\yikes01>main_test.run
zMain 01.

Greetings, Code 'Mon ...
zMain 02.

Project + makefile is at github, yet here is the later:
cc=gcc -v
opts = 
link = ld

ifdef OS
    libs = -LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lcrtdll 
else
    libs = -lc
endif

all: main_test2.run main_test.run Makefile

# First function becomes void main(void) ...
main_test2.run: main_test.c
    $(cc) $(opts) -c main_test.c
    $(link)  main_test.o -o main_test2.run $(libs)
    rm -f main_test.o
    
main_test.run: main_test.c
    gcc main_test.c -o main_test.run

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.run

Any ideas what's going spare, here? How to link in gmon_start?
Note: Swapping around parameters does indeed create some marginally different results - direct compliation at the CLI (main_test.run) always works.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example in the question itself, not off-site.

Don't know for mingw/windows. Interesting though, will have a poke at it later.

Change link = ld to link = gcc, in which case you can also discard libs = -lc.
The bare linker (ld) only links what you specify, which does not include program
startup code. When invoked via gcc (as is usual), gcc appends
boilerplate to the linker's commandline, including the required language runtime and
startup code.
After that change, you will be able to see the extra libraries and object files added to
the linkage if you inspect the output with gcc -v.

Changing the linker from ld to gcc and junking libc worked great for both compilers. Just updated the github demo. Thanks!

@RandallNagy What interested me was how the program linked, with the wrong entry point, on Windows at all. Anyhow if your problem is solved, consider What should I do when someone answers my question?

Yea - it seems that when there is no _start that it latched on to the first void(*)(void) and mapped the function to the man() - 'tre odd - and only on MinGW. Did so using an unusual collection to fix-up the beastie.
Was also amazed to see GNU on Linux simply pretened that the file was not there ... woof.
